# inconsistent Makefile behaviour when targets have no dependencies

Tags: makefile

Here is a quick and dirty Makefile to do a Latex pass for two documents.

```
BOOKDIR=/tmp/book
SLIDESDIR=/tmp/slides

LATEX=pdflatex -shell-escape --halt-on-error

book:
    mkdir -p "${BOOKDIR}"
    ${LATEX} -output-directory="${BOOKDIR}" book.tex && \
        (cd "${BOOKDIR}" && makeindex book)

slides:
    mkdir -p "${SLIDESDIR}"
    ${LATEX} -output-directory="${SLIDESDIR}" slides/slides.tex

all: book slides
```

When I run `make book`, it executes the recipe for book. When I run `make slides` it always says `make: 'slides' is up to date.`

Neither of these targets have any dependencies, so why is make not behaving the same in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the command

```
${LATEX} -output-directory="${SLIDESDIR}" slides/slides.tex
```

It appears that you have a directory called `slides` in the current directory.  Presumably you do not have one called `book`.  You can change the target name or change the directory name, or declare the targets as `.PHONY`, depending on the behavior that you want.